# How to update a branch with master on GitHub

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

I have a Sprint branch that was created prior to new updates on Master. Since then, the changes were pushed to the master branch, now I have to update the Sprint branch. I am trying to sync my Sprint branch with a master.

Is there a way to do it through github.com page, otherwise I am using PhpStorm VCS.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's simple and can be done by two command lines:

```
git checkout sprint
git merge origin/master
```

This will merge the remote master branch to the local sprint branch. So your local sprint branch is up to date like the master branch.

If you need to do this on **Github**.com, then create a PR(Pull Request) and then select two branches(base:sprint and compare:master) and then merge it.

[image: Github pull request with base: sprint, compare: master]

Comment: Ok. So I actually need to update a remote branch. I have master and Sprint branch on remote and I need to update Sprint branch from master

Comment: Yeah, after this operation, push changes to remote branch. That's it

Answer (score 6):

Try merging the master branch(with the latest changes) to your sprint branch. This will get your master commits (absent from the sprint branch) to your sprint branch.
Then merge your sprint branch(having commits absent from the master) to the master branch.

Through the Github Web page

```
1. Raise a pull request from master to sprint branch.
2. Merge the pull request using Github's UI.
3. Raise a pull request from sprint branch to master.
4. Merge the pull request.
```

Through Command Line

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout sprint
git merge master
git checkout master
git merge sprint
git push origin sprint
```

Comment: Read it carefully, trying to get it through the web not command line.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting, although not directly requested by you, that Github Desktop has hugely simplified this functionality. With "Current Repository" set to your repo and "Current Branch" set to your Sprint branch, simply chose from the menus:

Branch->Update from Master (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Mac OSX)

Once that's complete, you'll get a "Push Origin" button to push the changes to Sprint. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac OSX)

In short:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: In PhpStorm, you can do this with:
- Git -> Update project...
- select "merge" (resolve potential conflicts all at once) or "rebase" (resolve conflicts in the sprint branch commit by commit)
- Git -> Push...